# What's the difference between fabled and legendary?

Tags: meaning, differences

I'm currently preparing for proficiency test and I came across the following sentence:

'Wilfred Thesinger, the ... explorer once said, 'We live our lives second-hand''. The right answer is legendary

I looked both up at collins dictionary and saw legendary was regarded as a synonym of fabled (which was also one of the four options). Ever since I saw it I'm confused with.

If anyone could throw some light on the accurate difference, I would be grateful.

Thanks

Comment: Hi JD_PM, welcome to EL&U. It seems you have more than one question. Would you please edit your question and ask one question at a time. Thanks.

Comment: I will split my question in two, thank you for your advise

Comment: Well, if there are legends about you then you’re legendary.  If there are fables written about you then you are fabled.

Comment: "Legendary" also carries some overtones of "well-known" and "famous" to a general populace which can be applied to existing persons. "Fabled" also has a mild overtone of "well-known" and "famous", but this kind of fame (or infamy) is ascribed to things or persons that you heard as a child and didn't grow up expecting to eventually meet. Trolls, unicorns, fairies, and the such are fabled creatures.

Comment: Could you include the other two options, please?  I think the question is quite good and deserves a bit more attention.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Most people see no difference between "fabulous" and "legendary"; strictly, they’re wrong. "Legends" are expanded, distorted or twisted but necessarily based in reality. "Fables" may contain elements of fact but their nature is unreal; fantasy and imagination. The same story could be either, the problem being that doubt about content is clouded by doubt about scholarship about content…

Take Troy: for millenia before Schliemann “clearly” pure, invented fable; no war, no city, no beauty, no nothing. After Schliemann dug, legend clearly based on historical fact; not impossibly, pure truth.

Answer (score 5):

*Fabled* and *legendary* can be synonymous. You could equally well speak of the fabled ghost ship the *Flying Dutchman* or the legendary *Flying Dutchman*. But I think that *fabled* is more likely to suggest something fictional, whereas legendary is also applied to real things or people around which a legend has grown, and the legend might be fact or fiction or a mixture of both. You might refer to the legendary Abraham Lincoln, a real person, but not every story about him is true.